# Is there a way to determine where a script was executed from?

Tags: python, bash, module, callstack

I have a Python script which I'd like to do different things depending upon where it was execute. Sometimes I might execute it from the console and sometimes I might use a Bash script to in turn execute the Python script. Is there a way to differentiate the two?

I already know of the `inspect` module:

```py
import inspect

print(inspect.stack())
```

This can tell me the filename executing this code but not where the file itself was executed.

My intended use is when training a neural network, I want to output the epoch, error, accuracy per epoch. Sometimes I use a Bash script to instead collect data where I only care about the error. I have a toggle in my file right now which when set to true will provide a verbose output, and when false a simple output. I'd rather not need a toggle if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/).

To install `psutil`:

```
pip3 install psutil
```

This should get you all the details you require:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.Process().environ())
```